# What's the most efficient way to pull data for a large list from an RDMS?

Tags: database, performance

I'm working on a system with thousands of items that has to be presented to the user for selection. Each line item display consists of lots of data and options/links and has to read from many tables in a database to render all the information and links on the line. And there's thousands of lines.

So obviously we filter or paginate or in some way limit the resulting data set because we don't really need to show 4000 items on the page when the user is only going to pick one.

Let's say we paginate. The problem I see here is that in order to show page 3 for example, we have to know how many items per page and then somehow make an sql that retrieves only one page's worth 3 pages in. Keep in mind the list to display can be sorted by any of the many columns of data, so it seems to me we have to ask for the entire result set back from the database and then in the program pick off just the items from page 3 we want, because there's no way to say in SQL give me rows 30-40 from select blah blah blah order by x, y, z.

Then there's the problem of getting the data. I can do it in one pass getting all the data I'll ever need and then pick off rows 30-40 that I get back, but that's a lot of work on the database most of which I'm going to throw away.

So instead maybe I do one pass to get the list of identifiers, and then I make another much more complicated sql to get all the data I need for those 10 rows via an IN clause on some row identifier (that better be in the PK). Doing two passes for one page sounds like a really slow idea. I also find that the more work I ask the database to do, the more my DBA gets mad at me. So the ideal would be to dump as much work on the app server as possible, but that of course means pulling lots of data over the network from the database to the app server which is also a slow solution.

So is that the better way? Or is there another paradigm that works better?

Now let's say we're filtering. The user has some filter criteria they can select. We run into the same problem, where the user can remove all filters and then I'll end up loading 4000 really data intensive rows from the database, which pretty much requires that I do pagination anyway.

The goal here is to have quick google-like page times while being forced to read lots of data out of lots of tables to be able to render one page of information.

Over time I've come to realize that what google does isn't that complex. And by that I mean the result set of a search page has a fairly limited set of data. I don't question that how they go about getting that data is very complex, but any given search result isn't made up of that much information.

My problem is that I have lots of information in each line on the page I'm displaying, and I'm constrained by the limitation that all my data is spread out over a bunch of tables and databases.

So while I realize with the infrastructure I have I will never achieve google-like response times, what is the best way of going about rendering a page's worth of data from a database?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a way to have the database say "Give me rows 30-40 from my query".  What you're looking for is `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.  This is probably the best solution—it lets the database do what it's best at.

[Documentation for LIMIT and OFFSET](http://www.sql.org/sql-database/postgresql/manual/queries-limit.html).

Also, it sounds like you're in a perfect position to think about caching.  You've got a set of extremely expensive queries, but they don't seem to be changing quickly—using something like Memcached to keep a copy of your query results could be useful.

Comment: Interesting idea, memcached. I'll look up limit and offset, I always thought things like that were db specific extensions, not standard SQL, but I'll check it out.

Comment: ahhh, I see that's a postgresql thing. Not a universal sql expression.